# Will webpack be part of build?

Tags: reactjs, webpack-2

I have recently moved from gulp to webpack. In webpack I am chunking js into vendor, common and main.

I have one question if webpack code be part of anyof these chunks as its only dev dependency and not needed in production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your chunks will contain `webpack`'s essential code, that is necessary for bootstrapping your code bundle correctly. Webpack doesn't add unnecessary code to your chunks.